# <Script> code does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, wijmo

The below script snippet is from the Wijmo website itself, however does not work on my local web server. I tried to debug through the

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

However have no luck. Please suggest/help fix. Entire script below.

```
<script id="scriptInit" type="text/javascript">
require(["wijmo.wijgrid"], function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wijgrid").wijgrid({
         showFilter: true,
            data: [
            [27, 'Canada', 'Adams, Craig', 'RW'],
            [43, 'Canada', 'Boucher, Philippe', 'D', 'R'],
            [24, 'Canada', 'Cooke, Matt', 'LW', 'L'],
            [87, 'Canada', 'Crosby, Sidney (C)', 'C', 'L'],
            [1, 'United States', 'Curry, John', 'G', 'L'],
        ],
        columns: [
            {headerText: "Number"},
            {headerText: "Nationality"},
            {headerText: "Player"},
            {headerText: "Position"}
        ]
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Essentially I want to be able to

- Display a grid
- do some customization
- I am Including the cdn for grid as below

```html
<script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20143.24/controls/wijmo.grid.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20143.24/interop/angular/wijmo.angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20143.24/controls/wijmo.chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20143.24/styles/wijmo.min.css"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20143.24/controls/wijmo.min.js"></script>
```

[My plunk for reference here](http://plnkr.co/cStHD3)

Comment: The plunk doesn't show any grid. Can you check again.

Comment: @AbdiasM updated the plunk. Thanks for taking a look & pointing out

Comment: the plunk still doesn't show any grid.